# Как получить элементы из JSON Java Script?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

В Java Script не силён. Пытаюсь достать из JSON объекта `data` элемент.

Объект `data` был получен из строки `msg`, представляющей JSON, так: `var data = JSON.parse(msg);`

`alert(data)` выдаёт `{"str0":{"Id":1,"DevId":999,"State":255,"IP":0,"Data":5000},"str1":{"Id":2,"DevId":999,"State":255,"IP":0,"Data":5000},"str2":{"Id":3,"DevId":999,"State":255,"IP":0,"Data":5000},"str3":{"Id":4,"DevId":999,"State":255,"IP":0,"Data":5000}}` на мой взгляд нормальный JSON.

`alert(data["str0"])`, вопреки ожиданиям, выдаёт `undefined`

Вопрос прост: как получить элемент по ключу?

Дополнительная информация: JSON получен из ASP.NET Core с помощью `JavaScriptSerializer` из обычного словаря C#.

В визуализаторе JSON в Visual Studio вовремя отладки, возвращаемой методом Web API значение представляется корректно (показано на картинке).[image: json]

Comment: Так, вам именно для использования JavaScriptSerializer нужна сборка System.Net.Extensions.dll? В ASP.NET Core есть встроенные средства для работы с JSON. [Controller.Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnetcore-2.2) мethod.

Comment: Большое спасибо, хоть это и не относится к теме данного вопроса, Ваш комментарий очень полезен!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Но у меня этого метода почему-то нет. Ввожу `Controller.` и IDE подсказывает только `Equals` и `ReferenceEquals`. Если метод нестатический, подскажите, как им пользоваться.

Comment: Это экземплярный метод. [тыц](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2#format-specific-action-results)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вероятно, у меня снова что-то не подключено, т.к. IDE не видит этот метод.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод `JSON.parse()`:

```
let arr = JSON.parse(data);

alert(arr.str0);
```

[Тут пример с вашим JSON](https://playcode.io/383118?tabs=script.js,preview)

Comment: Простите за неполную информацию в вопросе, но метод уже был использован. Сейчас скорректирую.

Comment: @V-Mor посмотрите ссылку в ответе

Comment: Выводит `[object Object]`. Я согласен, что это лучше, чем `undefined`. Но я всё ещё не пойму, почему это не работает у меня.

Comment: @V-Mor покажите код всего куска с получением и обработкой json'а. Может там что будет

Comment: Вот он: `function (msg) {
                        let data = JSON.parse(msg);
                        alert(data);
                        alert(data.str0);
}`

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае было необходимо дважды выполнить операцию `JSON.parse` для окончательного преобразования. Вероятно, причина в добавленных ASP.NET Core символах `\`.

Answer (score 0):

После использования данной строки `var data = JSON.parse(msg);` и вызова `alert(data)`, вы получаете вот такую строку:
`{"str0":{"Id":1,"DevId":999,"State":255,"IP":0,"Data":5000},"str1":{"Id":2,"DevId":999,"State":255,"IP":0,"Data":5000},"str2":{"Id":3,"DevId":999,"State":255,"IP":0,"Data":5000},"str3":{"Id":4,"DevId":999,"State":255,"IP":0,"Data":5000}}`

это значит, что `msg` уже был переведён в объект после его получения, и не надо вызывать повторно `var data = JSON.parse(msg)` иначе Вы его повторно превращаете в JSON. В результате alert(data["str0"]) получается undefined, т.к. поиск значения объекта происходит в строке!!! Это говорит о том, что до метода `done()` или `success`(не знаю чем вы получаете значения в ajax) из-за заголовков или по другой причине происходит авто парсинг. В первом ответе на Ваш вопрос вам вызвали повторно данный метод с Вашими данными, и алерт получает `[object Object]`, это корректная обработка результата, Вам правильно подсказали! почитайте о том как работает с данными `alert()`. Для строк и чисел он вернёт данные, а для объектов он вернёт `[object Object]`. Замените `alert` на `console.log(data["str0"])` или `console.log(data.str0)` и вы Увидите результат

Comment: Насколько я понял из Вашего ответа, необходимо без парсинга сделать `console.log(msg.str0)`. Я сделал. Результат: `undefined`.

Comment: @V-Mor давайте по порядку! что произойдет когда вызываете `console.log(msg)`. Если выведет строку json, то необходимо вызвать `JSON.parse` и потом `console.log(data.str0)`

Comment: Вывод `console.log(msg)`: `{\"str0\":{\"Id\":1,\"DevId\":999,\"State\":255,\"IP\":0,\"Data\":5000},\"str1\":{\"Id\":2,\"DevId\":999,\"State\":255,\"IP\":0,\"Data\":5000},\"str2\":{\"Id\":3,\"DevId\":999,\"State\":255,\"IP\":0,\"Data\":5000},\"str3\":{\"Id\":4,\"DevId\":999,\"State\":255,\"IP\":0,\"Data\":5000},\"str4\":{\"Id\":5,\"DevId\":999,\"State\":255,\"IP\":0,\"Data\":5000},\"str5\":{\"Id\":6,\"DevId\":999,\"State\":255,\"IP\":0,\"Data\":5000}}`

Comment: Нашёл как исправить ситуацию. Спасибо, что навели на этот ответ.

Comment: @V-Mor Отлично у Вас вывелась строка JSON. Далее вызовите парсинг console.log(JSON.parse(msg)); У Вас должны появиться данные как на фотографии в вопросе! Ну или раз Вы нашли как решить ситуацию, то супер!

Comment: Двойной парсинг всё решил.

Comment: @V-Mor рад помочь!

Comment: Первая половина ответа - какой-то бред. Вторая верная.